# How to update in MySql columns

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

There are 5 columns **X** and **A**, **B**, **C**, **D** in table **t**. Columns **A**, **B**, **C**, **D** are varchar. and column **X** has to show us how many of the next row repeating characters. I need help to update column **X**.

Example :

```
|ID | X | A | B | C | D |
=========================
| 4 | 1 | 7 | J | 7 | Q |
| 3 | 2 | K | Q | 8 | 8 |
| 2 | 3 | 7 | 8 | 9 | J | next row X=3
| 1 | 0 | 7 | J | 8 | K | 0 default
```

ID-1 is the first and X is zero by default and from there begin calculations ID-2 and X=3 because we have ID-1 "7" "J" and "8" and the next row ID-2 have the combination "7 8 9 J" in ID-1 there "7 J 8 -" and X should be 3. Values ​​of X can be between 0 and 4. ID-3, X=2 "- - 8 8" because in ID-2 have the combination "7 8 9 J" and i have 8 - twice in "K Q 8 8".

Comment: I have no idea of how X is calculated.  Can you edit the question and provide more details.  Also note that in SQL, there is no "previous row".  You need an id or timestamp to specify the ordering.  And, tag the question with the database you are using.

Comment: please clarify how do you compute X and what do you mean by previous row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Added : 08/06

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4586e/1

```
CREATE TABLE tmp
(
    id int,
    alnum CHAR(1),
    cnt int,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, alnum)
);

INSERT INTO tmp (id, alnum, cnt) SELECT id, A, 1 FROM tab ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE cnt = cnt + 1;
INSERT INTO tmp (id, alnum, cnt) SELECT id, B, 1 FROM tab ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE cnt = cnt + 1;
INSERT INTO tmp (id, alnum, cnt) SELECT id, C, 1 FROM tab ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE cnt = cnt + 1;
INSERT INTO tmp (id, alnum, cnt) SELECT id, D, 1 FROM tab ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE cnt = cnt + 1;

UPDATE tab INNER JOIN (
    SELECT t1.id AS id, SUM(t2.cnt) AS sum
    FROM tmp t1 INNER JOIN tmp t2 ON t1.id + 1 = t2.id
        AND t1.alnum = t2.alnum
    GROUP BY t1.id
) tmp3 ON tab.id = tmp3.id + 1
SET tab.X = tmp3.sum;

SELECT * FROM tab WHERE X > 4;
```

### Original answer : 08/05

How about using `tmp` table which stores for each `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` columns into single rows. This makes us easy to calculate `X` value.
Below code assumes `id` is sequencial value. If not, please let me know there is another query for it.

```
CREATE TABLE tab
(
    id INT,
    X INT,
    A CHAR(1),
    B CHAR(1),
    C CHAR(1),
    D CHAR(1)
);

INSERT INTO tab VALUES (1, 0, '7', 'J', '8', 'K');
INSERT INTO tab VALUES (2, 0, '7', '8', '9', 'J');
INSERT INTO tab VALUES (3, 0, 'K', 'Q', '8', '8');
INSERT INTO tab VALUES (4, 0, '7', 'J', '7', 'Q');

CREATE TABLE tmp
(
    id INT,
    alnum CHAR(1)
);

INSERT INTO tmp SELECT id, A FROM tab;
INSERT INTO tmp SELECT id, B FROM tab;
INSERT INTO tmp SELECT id, C FROM tab;
INSERT INTO tmp SELECT id, D FROM tab;

UPDATE tab INNER JOIN (
    SELECT t1.id AS id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM tmp t1 INNER JOIN tmp t2 ON t1.id + 1 = t2.id
        AND t1.alnum = t2.alnum
    GROUP BY t1.id
) tmp3 ON tab.id = tmp3.id + 1
SET tab.X = tmp3.cnt;

mysql> SELECT * FROM tab ORDER BY id DESC;
+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| id   | X    | A    | B    | C    | D    |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+
|    4 |    1 | 7    | J    | 7    | Q    |
|    3 |    2 | K    | Q    | 8    | 8    |
|    2 |    3 | 7    | 8    | 9    | J    |
|    1 |    0 | 7    | J    | 8    | K    |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: There are more than 27,000 rows in database and **X** must be between 0 and 4. Unfortunately there does not calculate well.

Comment: @HaydayWxy I can't access dropbox at office network. Would you please post your data on http://www.sqlfiddle.com/ ?

Comment: @HaydayWxy All file sharing sites are blocked at office for security reason :(

Comment: @HaydayWxy I've found a problem. There were duplicated values in columns. e.g) `id=38` rows has `B` and `C` have same `Q`. I'll try to solve it.

Comment: Perfect, works very well thank you !!! Can you fix the problem with "select ((case when t1.A in (tnext.A,....." the second script? Thanks again.

Comment: @HaydayWxy Here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4586e/2 It looks like working. but I didn't check all `X` has correct value.

Answer (score 0):

The `X` values in your example are from the "next" row, not the previous.  Assuming you have an auto-incrementing id, you can calculate this information by looking at the next row.  You can generate a query to do the calculation:

```
select ((case when t1.A in (tnext.A, tnext.B, tnext.C, tnext.D) then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when t1.B in (tnext.A, tnext.B, tnext.C, tnext.D) then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when t1.C in (tnext.A, tnext.B, tnext.C, tnext.D) then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when t1.D in (tnext.A, tnext.B, tnext.C, tnext.D) then 1 else 0 end)
       ) as X, t1.*
from (select t.*, (select max(id) from table t2 where t2.id > t.id) as nextid
      from table t
     ) t1 left outer join
     t tnext
     on tnext.id = t1.nextid;
```

Depending on the database you are using, this code can be simplified and expressed differently.  Also, the specific update syntax might depend on the database.

Comment: Hi, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/88441/1, I tried but got error in calculations. In column 'X' calculations are correct in "table1".

Comment: Here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/88441/2 , Here I changed but still not calculated correctly after 6 rows id-6 is 1 - correct is 2.